# Artificial Horizont in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

I need an artificial horizont in silverlight. Any know some component?

[image]

Comment: If you need only the control looking like that and some basic presentation features (i.e. visualisation based on a given angle and height), creating  the control by yourself should not be too complicated.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer not an edit to your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks Lucas by your comment. I made my own control and looks like:

[image]